# ionic/angular wait until service is ready

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6

In my Ionic app I have api service which makes API calls to my backend. In constructor I have to wait for storage ready (async), retrieve client id from storage and only after allow making api calls. Problem is async/await is now allowed in constructor. Is there any best practices to implement such behaviour?

---

Comment: I would use the `.then()` method of the promise returned when storage is ready...

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid async/await stuff inside constructor. In Angular Constructor is a function, that should inject the required Dependency Injection and return it immediately, not return a promise that has to be awaited. That is considered a bad practice.

Instead. You can handle inside OnInit or custom functions.

Comment: Why downVote? you can’t have await statement in constructor, because constructor returns instance of object, not Promise<Object>